# Angular Dynamically generated select field where one is dependent on the other

Tags: angular

I have dynamically generated select fields.

1. There are 2 select fields. first: "category" and the second is: "object"
2. Select field "object" is dependent on the value of "category".
3. If category selected is "animal", object will display only: "Dog", "Cat", "Lion"
4. If category selected is "plant", object will display only: "Rose", "Coconut", "Apple"

Here is the angular HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="inventoryForm">
    <div formArrayName="items">
        <div *ngFor="let items of inventoryForm.get('items')['controls']; let i=index">

            <div [formGroupName]="i">

      <select formControlName="category" class="form-control">
        <option selected></option>
        <option *ngFor="let a of allCategories">{{a.category}} </option>
      </select>

                <select formControlName="object" class="form-control">
        <option selected></option>
        <option *ngFor="let b of allObjects">{{b.name}} </option>
      </select>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button (click)="addItem()">Add</button>
```

Here is the component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
allObjects;
allCategories;

inventoryForm: FormGroup;
items: FormArray;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}



ngOnInit() {

this.allObjects = [
{category: "Animal", name: "Dog"},
{category: "Animal", name: "Cat"},
{category: "Animal", name: "Lion"},
{category: "Plant", name: "Rose"},
{category: "Plant", name: "Coconut"},
{category: "Plant", name: "Apple"},
]

this.allCategories = [
{category: "Animal", },
{category: "Plant", }
]


  this.inventoryForm = new FormGroup({
    items: new FormArray([])
  });

}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    category: '',
    object: '',
  });
}

addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.inventoryForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}
}
```

And this the stackblitz Link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgzsnu

Comment: I found an old answer to a similar question, but I think it still applies if you adjust to newer version of angular. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710137/angular-2-how-to-populate-a-dropdown-based-on-another-dropdown-selection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a Pipe to filter your objects of second select.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'type',  pure: false })
export class TypePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(allObjects: [{category:string,name:string}], filter: string): any {
    if(filter == ''){
      return null
    }
    return allObjects.filter(object => object.category == filter)
  }
}
```

Then add the Pipe to your `*ngFor`

```
<option *ngFor="let b of allObjects | type : getType(i)">{{b.name}}</option>
```

And create your method `getType(i)`

```
getType(index){
  let temp_items = this.inventoryForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  return temp_items.controls[index].get('category').value;
}
```

Here the [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm3ey9)

Comment: Thank you! I figured that i need to do,     if(filter == 'Plant'), in my actual code, this can reach to more than a thousand because this is dynamic as well

Comment: your welcome :) If the solution is good for you, consider upvoting :)

Comment: I have no idea how to pass on a variable to Pipe Filter. The category examples "plant" and "animal" are database objects and could easily reach to more than a thousand and maximum to around 3 thousand. I can not possibly do if(filter == 'Plant'). Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Oh yes ... I have made something like a tautology moreover. I have updated and now you can even have 1 million of category, it will work ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
You can change the code like below.

<select formControlName="object" class="form-control">
        <option selected></option>
        <option *ngFor="let b of allObjects">{{b.name}} </option>
      </select>

To

    <select formControlName="object" class="form-control">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let b of allObjects">
        <option *ngIf="b.category == items.get('category').value" >{{b.name}} </option>
          </ng-container>
      </select>
```

Comment: Much better than my answer, I have forgot that we was iterating over the items at the beginning :/ +1

Comment: Can you please accept my answer , if it works for you.